# Excel VBA - Expand all Columns Toggle?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which requires all columns to be expanded and I am using this code to achieve this

```
Sub Expand_All()
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8, ColumnLevels:=8
End Sub
```

Is there a way to remember if a sheet group was collapsed/expanded before the operation so that it could be returned to its original state after the macro finishes?

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to find the hidden column range within a worksheet. You should be able to use it to store the range then hide it afterwards

```
Sub TestCols()
    Dim rHidden As Range: Set rHidden = HiddenColumns()
    'Your Code
    rHidden.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub

Function HiddenColumns(Optional wsSrc As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim UnusedRow As Long
    Dim HiddenStatus As Boolean: HiddenStatus = False
    If wsSrc Is Nothing Then Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wsSrc
        On Error GoTo ExitFunction
        UnusedRow = .Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlRows, xlPrevious).Row + 1
        With .Rows(UnusedRow)
            HiddenStatus = .Hidden
            .Hidden = False
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).value = "x"
            Set HiddenColumns = Range(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Address(0, 0))
            .Clear
            .Hidden = HiddenStatus
        End With
    End With

ExitFunction:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```